# Iquerable operation MVC

Tags: c#, linq

I am new in Iquerable.
I want to concatenate all item in "selectedBus" with OR, and all item in "depositi" with OR.
Then I want that the 2 predicate (predicate and predicate 3) are with AND operator.

```
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<tb_pulizie>();
    var predicate3 = PredicateBuilder.False<tb_pulizie>();
var result = Context.tb_pulizie.AsQueryable();
         if (selectedBus != null)
                        {
                           foreach (string keyword in selectedBus)
                            {
                                string temp = keyword;
                                predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.ID.Contains(temp));        
                            }
                            result = Context.tb_pulizie.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
                           // result = result.Where(predicate);
                        }

    if (depositi != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string keyword in depositi)
                        {
                            string temp = keyword;
                            predicate3 = predicate3.Or(p => p.deposito.Contains(temp));
                        }
                        result = Context.tb_pulizie.AsExpandable().Where(predicate3);

                    }
```

How can I do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest LINQKit (get it from NuGet) that has an ExpressionStarter to make handling `And` versus `Or` automatic, and the latest C# 7.0, you can have:

```
var predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.New<tb_pulizie>();
if (selectedBus != null)
    foreach (string keyword in selectedBus)
        predicate1 = predicate1.Or(p => p.ID.Contains(keyword));

var predicate2 = PredicateBuilder.New<tb_pulizie>();
if (depositi != null)
    foreach (string keyword in depositi)
        predicate2 = predicate2.Or(p => p.deposito.Contains(keyword));

var result = Context.tb_pulizie.AsExpandable().Where(predicate1.And(predicate2));
```